# How to display the name of a user logged with Firebase in another UIViewController

Tags: swift, authentication

I want to display the username from my firabase database in another UIViewController but I don't know how. Now the name it's "test" but it's only an example so if another user logs into my app they should see his name on the screen.

Here you have my database setup:

```
exsample-bde49

users:

profile: oAPjqYRrO1NADm1i1YH1qK7FOk53
photoURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/exs..."     

username: "test"
```

Here you have my LoginViewController with the handleSignIn func:

```
@objc func handleSignIn() {
    guard let email = emailField.text else { return }
    guard let pass = passwordField.text else { return }

    setContinueButton(enabled: false)
    continueButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    activityView.startAnimating()

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass) { user, error in
        if error == nil && user != nil {
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Error logging in: \(error!.localizedDescription)")

           self.restforms()
        }
    }
}
```

And Here you have my code for my HomeViewController where i will like the username displayed.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeViewController:UIViewController {

    @IBAction func nextViewButton(_ sender: Any) {

        print("test press")

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"seccondview", sender: self)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func handleLogout(_ sender:Any) {
        try! Auth.auth().signOut()
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func logout(_ sender: Any) {
        try! Auth.auth().signOut()
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create variable in the next view controller then set it before present nextViewController you can trigger when you are performing any segue  as following code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "seccondview" {
        if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? NextViewController  {
                nextViewController.userName = "userNameYouWantToPass" 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed 

So do not need to edit the LoginViewController?